# c# case sensitive ASCII sort?

Tags: c#, sorting, ascii

i need to sort an string Array and it MUST be sorted by ascii.

if using Array.Sort(myArray), it won't work.

for example:
myArray is ("aAzxxxx","aabxxxx")
if using Array.Sort(myArray)
the result will be

1. aabxxxx
2. aAzxxxx

but if ascii sort, because A < a, (capital A is 65, a is 97, so A < a)
the result will be

1. aAzxxxx
2. aabxxxx

this is the result i need. any ideas about how to ASCII sort an string Array?

thx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you want to perform an Ordinal comparison.

```
Array.Sort(myArray, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want a lexical sort by the char-code you can supply `StringComparer.Ordinal` as a comparer to `Array.Sort`.

```
Array.Sort(myArray,StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

> The StringComparer returned by the Ordinal property performs a simple byte comparison that is independent of language. This is most appropriate when comparing strings that are generated programmatically or when comparing case-sensitive resources such as passwords.

The [`StringComparer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx) contains several different comparers from which you can choose depending on which culture or case-sensitivity you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use an overload of [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9771wchs.aspx) that takes a suitable [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx):

```
Array.Sort(myArray, StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
```

This sort is *case sensitive*.

If you are looking for a sorting by the *ASCII value*, use `StringComparer.Ordinal`:

```
Array.Sort(myArray, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Comment: Using StringComparer.InvariantCulture will result in the same ordering as the op was already getting. To get the result the op expects StringComparer.Ordinal is required.