# Sorting inputted letters in O(n) time

Tags: c, performance, big-o

I've heard about this from a friend with respect to an interview he had and we're both confused as to how the solution is found. He was given the following situation:
Characters are inputted one by one in an unsorted order. Output these letters in alphabetical order (capitalized letters first), in O(n) time.

So the span of the letters inputted are 'A' -> 'Z' and 'a' -> 'z'. 
Obviously this wouldn't work by moving the letters into an array and sorting them (due to the time complexity needed).
So how would this work? Is there a trick you'd do while you're reading in the letters?

Comment: If they're unique, a binary search tree would donit

Comment: @erewok they aren't unique. They can be repeated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Comment: radix sort -- allocate 26 * 2 characters in an array which holds buckets. Do a linear pass through the string of characters, and for each character, put the right character into the right bucket. The results are then sorted in one linear pass.

Answer (score 5):

The [trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) is to allocate an array of size `52`, and count number of occurrences of each letter. Then just scan that array from left to right, and print each letter that many times.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) and it's applicable in any situation where you're sorting a fixed range or a flat distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Sort > Ascii ascending. It's all taken care of for you.

Comment: This might help:    https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Ordinal-String-Sorting-1cbac582/description

Comment: Here is a stackOverFlow reference for just what you are looking for       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914010/c-sharp-case-sensitive-ascii-sort